# AngularJS: get object property in array by matching a different property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, wordpress

I have an array of products, displayed in a table with an AngularJS ng-repeat.

The products are an array of objects returned from a Wordpress REST API call, and each object has a "category", which returns as a number.

Example: `{ "name": "Foo", "cat": 12 }`

I can't simply bind to the "cat" property, since it displays "12" and I want to display the category label instead.

I can query for the list of all categories, and get an array like so:

```
[
    { label: 'Customer Engagement Solutions', id: 2 },
    { label: 'Small and Medium Business', id: 13 },
    { label: 'Customer Information Management', id: 4 },
    { label: 'eCommerce', id: 25 },
    { label: 'Location Intelligence', id: 16 },
    { label: 'Enterprise', id: 12 }
]
```

My product above, "Foo" should display "Enterprise", which is 12.

I know I can bind to a function, as in `{{ctrl.getCat(product)}}` but I'm not sure how to do the matching of the `ID` in the product to the one in the category array, and return the category *label*.

This is trivial to do in actual Wordpress PHP as they provide a function for this very task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a new array of products that already maps the categories. When you initialize the controller with the products and categories, create a new array the maps it.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  const _categories = [
    { label: 'Customer Engagement Solutions', id: 2 },
    { label: 'Small and Medium Business', id: 13 },
    { label: 'Customer Information Management', id: 4 },
    { label: 'eCommerce', id: 25 },
    { label: 'Location Intelligence', id: 16 },
    { label: 'Enterprise', id: 12 }
  ];
  
  const _products = [
    { "name": "Foo", "cat": 12 },
    { "name": "Bar", "cat": 16 },
    { "name": "Foo Bar", "cat": 12}
  ]
  
  let categoryMap = {}
  
  _categories.forEach( (category)=>{
    categoryMap[category.id] = category.label;
  })
  
  this.products = _products.map( (product)=>{
    return {
      "name": product.name,
      "category": categoryMap[product.cat]
    }
  })
  
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="product in ctrl.products">
      <span>Name: {{product.name}}</span>&nbsp;<span>Category: {{product.category}}</span>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#find()` or even more performant is create a hashmap of the category labels using `id` as property keys

Using find()

```
ctrl.getCat = function(product){
  let cat = categories.find(e => e.id === product.cat)
  return cat ? cat.label : 'Unknown';
}
```

Or as hashmap:

```
ctrl.catLabels = categories.reduce((a,c) => { a[c.id] = c.label; return a;},{})
```

Then in view:

```
{{ctrl.catLabels[product.cat]}}
```

Comment: That code throws an error when I run it through babeljs.  Doesn't like the last line, `unknown: Unexpected token, expected :` 
p

I need to convert it to ES5.

Comment: Ooops ...need to replace second `?` with `:` ... see update